# If $5^{(3x)} = 25^{(y+2)}$ and $x-2y=8$, then what is $x-y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The Question is

> If $5^{(3x)} = 25^{(y+2)}$ and $x-2y=8$, then what is $x-y$ ?

The proposed answer:

[image: If $5^{(3x)} = 25^{(y+2)}$ and $x-2=8$, then what is $x-y$]

I do understand the first part that

$3x=2y+4$

But the rest of the answer contains certain assumptions that I do not know of.

Could someone point me to those assumptions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to notice in this question is that your right side can be expressed as the same base as your left. For instance:

$$5^{3x} = 5^{2(y+2)}$$

From here, you can equate both of the exponents since the bases are equal:

\begin{align}
&3x = 2(y+2) \\
&3x = 2y+4
\end{align}

Now, from here, you'll have two equations which you need to solve i.e.

\begin{align}
&x-2y = 8 \\
&3x = 2y + 4
\end{align}

I won't say exactly how to do it but here's a hint: **rearrange one variable in terms of another and substitute**.

If you need a further clarification, don't hesitate to post a comment on any of the posts.

Comment: Thanks, I will do the rest

Comment: Anytime! I'm not aware if you have read the FAQ or not but if you found an answer useful (not necessarily mine) then after a certain period of time (15 minutes), you can "accept" the answer. Accepting the answer means clicking the checkmark beside the answer, below the up/down vote buttons. By accepting an answer you are giving a "thank you" the answer-er and closing a "loop" so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

This is just solving simultaneous equation. First part which you managed to understand is the tricky bit all other parts is just solving simultaneous equation.